# Initialising Algolia in Firebase Cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am using the Algolia extension for Firebase. In Algolia I have an index with many docuemnts. Each user of my app should access only the documents they created. In order to implement this filter I need to generate a specific, filtered API key in Algolia for each user. I am trying to do this with a cloud function in Fireabse.

I get an error when I try to initialize Algolia in my local cloud functions index.js file and then deploy the functions.

Combining the docs of Cloud Functions and Algolia, I am doing this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();



// For the default version
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

// For the default version
// import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';

// For the search only version
// import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';

const client = algoliasearch('appId', 'AdminApiKey');
const index = client.initIndex('profiles');
```

I haven't written any Algolia function yet, so I know that the error comes from this initialisation. (My other non-Aloglia cloud functions are running fine). And the Algolia search function installed automatically as a Firebase extension works fine too.

This is the error I get in the terminal when trying to deploying the cloud functions:

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.      

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        writeToFirestore(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: what errors u get

Comment: I just edited the question to include the error, thanks.

Comment: Can you double check if your deployed function is named `writeToFirestore()`, if you do have can you try to delete and re-deploy. also can you please include your logs to produce the specific error using the command `firebase deploy --debug`.

Comment: Thanks, when i run `firebase deploy --debug` I get a huge amount of text. Not sure how to share this here. I did some more tests so basically when I: 1/ deploy index.js with no functions, only initialisation of Cloud Functions and Algolia, it works. 2/ Deploy my only function writeToFirestore() without Algolia initialisation, it works. 3/ Deploy the same function with both initalisations (Firebase and Algolia) it fails. I noted that my Algolia extension is installed in the europe-west1 location, but my writeToFirestore() function is in us-central1. Tried to change region but it failed.

Comment: And yes I checked my function is named correctly

Comment: Can you provide a snippet/link of your `logs`? so we can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I found the issue, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end the problem was that I had not installed the algoliasearch package in the Firebase Cloud Functions directory but in the parent (root) directory of the app.